# ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.OAuth2ResourceServerConfiguration

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-cloud

I'm setting up a microservice application using spring boot and spring cloud, and want to add oauth2 authentication.

I use java 11 and module-info for jar dependencies but I failed to run it as spring boot application on Eclipse. I was able to compile with maven.

ResourceServer configuration:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.RemoteTokenServices;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.ResourceServerTokenServices;

import com.XXXXXXX.config.ApplicationPropertiesConfiguration;

@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class CustomResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationPropertiesConfiguration applicationPropertiesConfiguration;

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().anonymous().and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/newaccountbook", "/api/param/**")
                .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ResourceServerTokenServices tokenServices() {
        final RemoteTokenServices remoteTokenServices = new RemoteTokenServices();
        remoteTokenServices.setClientId(applicationPropertiesConfiguration.getOauthClientId());
        remoteTokenServices.setClientSecret(applicationPropertiesConfiguration.getOauthClientSecret());
        remoteTokenServices.setCheckTokenEndpointUrl(applicationPropertiesConfiguration.getCheckTokenUrl());
        return remoteTokenServices;
    }
}
```

module-info.java:

```
    requires commons.lang;
    requires feign.core;
    requires jackson.annotations;
    requires java.annotation;
    requires java.persistence;
    requires java.sql;
    requires java.transaction;
    requires java.validation;
    requires opencsv;
    requires org.hibernate.orm.core;
    requires org.hibernate.validator;
    requires org.mapstruct;
    requires slf4j.api;
    requires spring.beans;
    requires spring.boot;
    requires spring.boot.autoconfigure;
    requires spring.cloud.commons;
    requires spring.cloud.context;
    requires spring.cloud.openfeign.core;
    requires spring.context;
    requires spring.core;
    requires spring.data.commons;
    requires spring.data.jpa;
    requires spring.orm;
    requires spring.security.config;
    requires spring.security.oauth2;
    requires spring.security.web;
    requires spring.tx;
    requires spring.web;
    requires spring.webmvc;
    requires tomcat.embed.core;
```

pom.xml
**edit**: add spring cloud version

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR2</spring-cloud.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.2.0.Final</org.mapstruct.version>

    </properties>   
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-properties-migrator</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId> <!-- use mapstruct-jdk8 for Java 8 or higher -->
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zipkin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>4.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.OAuth2ResourceServerConfiguration$ResourceServerCondition
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader.loadClass(RestartClassLoader.java:144) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398) ~[na:na]
    at spring.core@5.1.8.RELEASE/org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:275) ~[spring-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.core@5.1.8.RELEASE/org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:315) ~[spring-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54804005/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-boot-context-properties-bi

Comment: @RobertBain I use  Springboot version 2.1.x  as suggested but still doesn't work out. I can clean install with maven  without errors.

Comment: That will be downloaded automatically because of the `spring-cloud-starter-oauth2` dependency. Can you run `mvn spring-boot:run` and see if you can start your application?

Comment: @TYsewyn Yes with the `mvn spring-boot:run` I can start my application. Any idea why doesn't it work with eclipse run as Spring boot App?

Comment: I don't use Eclipse myself so I won't be of much help here.
But just a wild guess here, can you add the dev tools in comment and try to start the application from Eclipse.

Comment: @TYsewyn I removed the dev tools but still got the error. I can even build and run inside docker but failed with Eclipse. Anyway, thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: Can you check which Java compiler/runtime Eclipse is using, it might be that it's not the same as the one that's installed on your system.
If your app can run with `mvn spring-boot:run` and in a docker container, then it will definitely be an issue with your IDE. :)

Answer (score 1):

First at all, **OAuth2 is not to authenticate**, it is to authorize a third to access to private information from a resource server.

If you want to implement the OAuth2 process, you need to have a resource server, an authorizer and the third system will access the information.

Here there is more information:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2

In your project, you need to add the OAuth2 dependency.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurityoauth2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```